# The image style "object-fit: contain" is broken in Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.109

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have recently updated to `Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)` in my mac and things are breaking now.

The reason behind having bit complex nested markup is because I need to show the image placed in centre of the `div` respective of image being different size but proportionally resized inside square div. So, all this was working fine before updating to new google chrome.

```css
.g-parent {
  width: 150px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.my-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
</div>

<h4>Show above image inside below div</h4>

<div class="g-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why it was working as [`height:100%` should fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/8620333) in this case since there is no height set in the parent container. So the actual behavior seems to be the correct one.

You can make the image to be `position:absolute` to fix this:

```css
.g-parent {
  width: 150px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.child > img {
  position:absolute;
}
.my-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
</div>

<h4>Show above image inside below div</h4>

<div class="g-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify this using one div:

```css
.g-parent {
  width: 150px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: gray;
}

.my-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
</div>

<h4>Show above image inside below div</h4>

<div class="g-parent">
  <div class="parent" style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.g-parent {
  width: 150px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.my-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
</div>

<h4>Show above image inside below div</h4>

<div class="g-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img class="my-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```